# Toggle Bar responsiveness issue

Tags: html, button, navbar, responsive, shrink

I have written code using bootstrap. But my issue is in the Toggle bar , like when I shrink the size to see my Web page responsive or not then the toggle bar is not open.
It shows the three button but when i click then it is not expanding.
Please give me suggestions to get rid of this issue.
Thanks.
**Html code**

```
    <section>
    <div id="container1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="scroll nav-link" href="#home" style = "color: #ffff;">HOME</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="scroll nav-link" href="#about" style = "color: #ffff;">ABOUT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="scroll nav-link" href="#services"style = "color: #ffff;">SERVICES</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="scroll nav-link" href="#contacts" style = "color: #ffff;">CONTACTS</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

**Css code**

    #container1{  
        margin-top:5rem ;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
     }
     #container1 ul li  {  
         margin-left: 8rem;
         margin-right: -5rem;
         border-right: 0.0625rem solid grey;  
     }
     #container1 ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #5e9ee7;   
     }
```

Comment: You need to share your code and maybe a printscreen or 2 about the problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have re-edit my code by putting html and css code. Please give me solutions to start my toggle bar menu

Answer (score 0):

I just get rid of my issue that I have arose a few hours ago. I finally got a fix of my problem. It only happens by removing "bs" which is present in between (data-bs-toggle="collapse") and in (data-bs-target="#navbarNav") in the html code.